# Ошибка System.FormatException: "Входная строка имела неверный формат."

Tags: c#

Проблема появляется в строке 42 на второй раз в первом цикле. Подскажите с чем это связано??

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test.Esey_Math
{
    public class Standart_Math
    {
        public double result_math;
        private int x = 1;
        private int SRV_Z(int x)
        {
            if(x == 0) { x = 1; }
            return x;
        }
        public int Shear_Znak(string str)
        {
            int res = 0;
            int[] srv = new int[5];
            if(str.Contains('+')) { srv[0] = str.IndexOf('+'); } else { srv[0] = 5000; }
            if (str.Contains('-')) { srv[1] = str.IndexOf('-'); } else { srv[1] = 5000; }
            if (str.Contains('*')) { srv[2] = str.IndexOf('*'); } else { srv[2] = 5000; }
            if (str.Contains('/')) { srv[3] = str.IndexOf('/'); } else { srv[3] = 5000; }
            if (str.Contains('=')) { srv[4] = str.IndexOf('='); } else { srv[4] = 5000; }
            res = srv.Min();
            if(x > 0) { x = x - 1; } else { x = 0; }
            return res;
        }
        public void Chet_1(int x, string strt)
        {
            double[] number = new double[50];
            char[] znak = new char[25];
            int vv = 0;
            int i = -1;
            strt= strt.Remove(0, x + 2);
            do
            {
                i++;
                vv = Shear_Znak(strt);
                number[i] = Convert.ToDouble(strt.Remove(vv, strt.Length -SRV_Z(vv)));
                strt = strt.Remove(0,vv);
                znak[i] = Convert.ToChar(strt.Remove(1, strt.Length - 1));
            } while (znak[i] != '=');
            i = -1;
            do
            {
                i++;
                switch (znak[i])
                {
                    case '-':
                        number[i + 1] = number[i] - number[i + 1];
                        break;
                    case '+':
                        number[i + 1] = number[i] + number[i + 1];
                        break;
                    case '*':
                        number[i + 1] = number[i] * number[i + 1];
                        break;
                    case '/':
                        number[i + 1] = number[i] / number[i + 1];
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            } while (znak[i] != '=');
            result_math = number[i];
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: А какая проблема появляется в строке 42, и на второй раз чего?

Comment: дайте я угадаю - вот это строка 42 `number[i] = Convert.ToDouble(strt.Remove(vv, strt.Length -SRV_Z(vv)));` ? Чему же равно вот это ваше выражение `strt.Remove(vv, strt.Length -SRV_Z(vv))` во время ошибки?